# Confluent Kafka: Should I poll after producing a message when I have set the acks to 0?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-kafka-python

I want to optimize my kafka producer (working in python using the `confluent-kafka` library). I have a topic for which acknowledgment of the leader receiving a message is not important. Therefore, I've set the [acks to 0](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#acks).

I'm wondering something about the above though: Does this really mean that no `acknowledgment` is sent *at all*? Thus I do not need to `poll()` after producing? Or would I risk a filling up an internal Queue if I don't poll after producing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before I set the answer, I didn't understand your second question (please share an example).For the first one, ack=0 mean that the producer sent the message to the broker without waiting any response (for example, if that broker crash before replicating, the message will be lost)

Comment: Hey @ahmed.ettoumi! 

So from my understanding, after producing a message, a delivery report is returned which updates the producer on e.g. errors in case of failure to send the message to a partition. These delivery reports can be polled for using the `poll()` function.

My question here is: If `acks=0`, does polling for a delivery report still make sense? Considering this configuration basically says: _"I don't require any acknowledgement from the broker if it went okay or not"_. 

My assumption would be: No, polling is not required in that case.

Does this make more sense?